# How to re-index an AuditLog table? non clustered primary key, clustered covering index, guid

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

Using SQL Server 2016 Standard. I have an existing `AuditLog` table, with a PK on a `bigint` column (generated C# side) and an additional index.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditLog]
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChangeTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [User] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [RootId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EntityId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EntityName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Operation] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [OldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [NewValue] [varchar](max) NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditLog] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditLog] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AuditLog_RootId] 
    ON [dbo].[AuditLog] ([RootId] ASC)
```

With the current 105,000,000 rows, the sizes are (using used_page_count * 8K per page):

- PK_AuditLog: 11,535,112 KB
- IX_AuditLog_RootId: 2,370,480 KB

I now have to create rows in this table from a stored procedure in SQL, not in c# only anymore, so I need a primary key that can be generated SQL side (and C# still). I think my choices are `int identity` and `guid` (with a `NEWSEQUENTIALID` default).

Since most of my usages include the date and ordering by date, I'm thinking of clustering with that. Sounds right?

And since I almost always filter by `RootId` and `User`, I'm thinking of including them in my index. Is it a good idea to include the other columns in the clustered index? or should they be in a separate covering index?

Every index needs to identify rows uniquely, so my clustered index will include the primary key even if I don't specify it. So using a `Guid` as the PK seems a bad idea for storage, particularly with 100million rows. So I'm using a `bigint`.

Since my PK is notclustered (therefore not stored physically in that order), how does SQL Server work out the next identity? I doubt it sorts the PK to find the max value. Is using identity on a nonclustered column a bad idea?

Also, I guess I could use `datetime2` with precision 3 (storage 7 bytes) instead of `datetime` (8 bytes) to keep same precision but save a bit of space (or even precision 4 to increase precision for same storage anyway)?

So I'm thinking of doing:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditLog
(
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ChangeTime datetime2(4) NOT NULL...


ALTER TABLE AuditLog   
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditLog] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_AuditLog_ChangetimeRootUser 
    ON AuditLog(Changetime, RootId, [User])
```

**Footnote**

This is how the table is used:

- No foreign keys to or from this table.
- insert heavy (any add/edit/delete of user entity fields inserts a new AuditLog row, constantly during business hours, must be fast)
- occasional reads (users check what or who changed something, ie, read the AuditLog, a few times a day, would be nice to not wait ages for a query to return)
- AuditLog rows are never updated nor deleted once inserted.

Typical filters and order:

- filter by date only
- filter by date and user
- filter by date and objectId
- filter by date and user and objectId
- filter by objectId only
- almost always sorted by reverse date, to show most recent changes first.
- often used with paging, using "offset x rows" and "fetch next x rows only"
- and a specific use case, which amounts to selecting a subset of PK using a where clause, and then self join on the main table using the PK to retrieve column values

PS: I'm clear on the process and the time it will take, create temporary new table, copy data in chunks, create indexes, etc...

Comment: Have you considered using a Clustered Columnstore for this table? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview

Answer (score 1):

*Since most of my usages include the date and ordering by date, I'm thinking of clustering with that. Sounds right?*

There is no way to know without doing it and evaluating the results.

*Is it a good idea to include the other columns in the clustered index?*

You cannot include columns in the clustered index because it makes little sense. The clustered index **is ultimately** the table. You include columns in a NC index to avoid additional lookup to access other columns of the rows.

*how does SQL Server work out the next identity?*

Quite frankly, don't worry about it. The engine manages the identity at the table level - it does not need to refer to any specific rows to determine the next value.

*Also, I guess I could use datetime2 with precision 3 (storage 7 bytes) instead of datetime (8 bytes) to keep same precision but save a bit of space (or even precision 4 to increase precision for same storage anyway)?*

**DO NOT** handicap your data just to save a single byte per row. Choose the correct datatype according to your requirements. Storage is cheap. A lack of precision is forever.

In addition, your footnotes are not clear. You refer to add/update/delete of user entity fields (which is a meaningless term to those unfamiliar with your schema) and also to "never updated nor deleted". That seems to be a contradiction, which may or may not be relevant.

And one final comment. Change involves risk. If your current schema is sufficient, then the **safest** approach is to simple recreate your table with your ID column as an identity (and everything else remains the same).

Comment: Clustering on a date column since most of my usages include the date and order by date: you say "can't tell without doing and evaluating". Hmmm. I would have thought that thinking and debating pros and cons before doing is a good idea,  highlighting pitfalls, or maybe it's a well known bad idea, etc. etc.

Comment: Clustered index is ultimately the table, so no sense in adding columns to it: that makes sense. Not worrying about the identity column, well, I won't worry once I know how it works. This article explains it, I should have searched first. Sql does not need to scan any rows, the value is stored in  syscolpars (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135950/where-does-sql-server-physically-store-the-identity-value-for-a-table)

Comment: I don't understand your comment about handicaping my data. As far as I can tell, datetime has 3 digits fractional seconds, and is stored as 8 bytes. datetime2 with precision 3 or 4 does not reduce my precision, and is stored as 7 bytes. So I do not handicap my data or loose precision, I would just save 100MB out of 11GB for 100million rows. Not much, I know.

Comment: As for the footnote, thanks, sorry, I meant a new row is inserted into AuditLog for every field updated in a user entity elsewhere in the database. What is never updated or delete are the AuditLog rows. Once inserted, they stay forever, untouched. Edited post.